# How to handle optional groups in regex and remove trailing spaces of result

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract a string and the content of an optional bracket, but I don't know how to handle the optional bracket:

```
lorem, ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem, ipsum (X123), 
lorem ipsum (X.12), 
lorem ipsum    (X.12), 
lorem ipsum (X1)
```

I'm trying it with the regex `/(.*)\((.*?)\)/gm`, but this won't handle the first two lines. For the first two lines the result for the second group is empty.
Also I would like to get rid of the trailing spaces of the text result.

The expected result should be `lorem ipsum` or `lorem, ipsum` for the first group and `X123`/ `X.12` / `X1` for the second group.

https://regex101.com/r/ZcCLCL/2

Comment: What part(s) of your input are you expecting to match? Can you provide the expected result?

Comment: You can use `[^()]` to find everything which is not a parenthesis

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex `/^(.+?)\s*(?:\((.+?)\))?[,\s]*$/`.

Explanation:

```
^   beginning of line
 (.+?)   lazily capture one or more characters
      \s*   zero or more spaces
         (?:   begin unnamed capturing group
            \(   literal parenthesis
              (.+?)   lazily capture one or more of any character
                   \)   literal parenthesis
                     )?   end unnamed capturing group and make it optional
                       [,\s]*   zero or more spaces or commas
                             $   end of line
```

```js
const pattern = /^(.+?)\s*(?:\((.+?)\))?[,\s]*$/gm;

const s= `lorem, ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem, ipsum (X123), 
lorem ipsum (X.12), 
lorem ipsum    (X.12), 
lorem ipsum (X1)`;

for (let m; m = pattern.exec(s); console.log(m));
```

Comment: Only the content of the brackets is needed. Is it possible to remove the brackets from the result?

Comment: Sure, just swap the literal parens and the capturing group parens. Does the update do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that maybe this expression, or a modified version of that,

```
^([^(]*?)$|^([^(]*)((?:\(([^)]*?)\))?)
```

might work.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/T5KNhH/1)

Comment: The first match has a result of three lines. In this example there should be six matches